# How do I create a column based on the values of two existing columns?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, time-series

I am working with a Pandas DataFrame containing a 20-year sample of monthly stock prices and corresponding returns for hundreds of different stocks. After sorting the sample by 'Date' and by 'Book-To-Market' ('B/M', for short), I want to create a column that assigns a value of -1 to the stock returns of the companies with the lowest B/M and a value of 1 to the stock returns of the companies with the highest B/M (half of the sample assigned -1 and the other half assigned 1) for *every month* in the sample.

I tried creating DataFrames for every month in the sample and attribute the values thereon, but I found it unpractical. Please find code below:

```
df = df.sort_values (by = ['Date','B/M'], ascending = True)
df

# Example of desired outcome (Note: 'Date' - dtype='datetime64[ns] - has been set as the index).

    Date        Company Name       B/M      Monthly Return       Signal
|2000-01-31 |      ORACLE     |   0.29  |      0.048         |     -1     |
|2000-01-31 |    MICROSOFT    |   0.37  |      0.032         |      1     |
|...        |...              |...      |...                 |...         | 
|2000-02-29 |    MICROSOFT    |   0.08  |      0.016         |     -1     |
|2000-02-29 |     ORACLE      |   0.30  |      -0.07         |      1     |
```

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Perhaps you could compute an intermediate value of the average `B/M` value for a given month. And then create the `Signal` column, keying of this average.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, please first calculate the median of B/M

```
bm_median=df["B/M"].median()
```

Then create a column where you check if the B/M is smaller than the median

```
df["signal"]=df["B/M"]<bm_median
```

Then if false, replace with 1 and if true replace with -1

```
df["signal"].replace(False,1,inplace=True)
df["signal"].replace(True,-1,inplace=True)
```